# PHP code not executing on AWS web server?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, httpd.conf

I have an AWS EC2 instance that I'm running my website on. I have set up and installed PHP and PostGreSQL on the instance via PuTTY and loaded my website files onto it. However, the PHP code is not executing at all on my website and I really don't know why.

A few prerequisites to my question before people offer suggestions:

1. I have modified the `httpd.conf` file and added the correct `MIME Type` for PHP and loaded the correct modules using the `LoadModule` markup.
2. I have installed PHP on the server which I have confirmed using `which php`.
3. I am using the correct `<?php` and `?>` tags.

I have no idea why my AWS isn't running my PHP scripts and as I have a heavily PHP driven website, this is becoming an issue.

Has anyone got any other suggestions?

Comment: What does php -v in command line return ?

Comment: P.s. might sound like a no brainer but did you restart apache after making the changes ?

Comment: What are you seeing? Is the server outputting php code which would mean php is not installed correctly? or are you getting a blank page probably with a 500 error?